# Overlay rasters from 2 different coordinate systems

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, datum

I'm trying to overlay SAR (10m-res) and IFSAR (5m-res) rasters.

I tried to project both using the PROJECT RASTER function of ArcGIS to the same coordinate system, but they won't overlay properly.

The SAR was said to be originally in WGS84 while the IFSAR was in PRS92.

I do not have access to their "original" state and I am not sure how many transformations the data have undergone which is what I think is causing my dilemma.

When I received the data, the SAR was already in WGS_84_UTM_Zone_51N with datum of D_WGS_1984 while the IFSAR was already in UTM_Zone_51_North_Hemisphere with datum D_Philippine_Reference_System_1992.

How can I overlay these without manually pulling/georeferencing the rasters?

Comment: How much does they not overlap? If it is around 1/2 pixel it might also be due to raster resampling options.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I set the layer properties to WGS_84_UTM_Zone_51N. Loaded the SAR DEM which uses WGS_84_UTM_Zone_51N with datum of D_WGS_1984. I then loaded the IFSAR DEM which uses UTM_Zone_51_North_Hemisphere with datum D_Philippine_Reference_System_1992. There is about 150+ meter distance between the 2 DEM. I tried to use the Project Raster tool and import the coordinate system of the SAR. Now the CS of the projected IFSAR is WGS_84_UTM_Zone_51N with datum of D_WGS_1984 as well. There is still an offset of about 150+m.